# Is there a way to pass a variable to Cloud Firestore Query .limit function in Angular

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Im Querying Firestore with pagination, which  I handle with a dropdown for user to display the desire amount of rows visible in a table.

I've tried passing a variable with the value from dropdown as number, but the query is not working

```
    paginatedQuery(start: any, rows: number, direction: boolean) {    
    const dbReference = this.afs.collection('dbcollection', ref => ref.orderBy('field').limit(rows).startAt(start);
    return dbReference.get();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "the query is not working"? Does it error out? If so, what is the error message? Does it return anything at all? Or is it the `.limit` ignore, and it returns everything? Have you thrown a `console.log(limit)` before your `const dbReference = ...` to ensure you're actually receiving the number that you think?

Comment: Im receiving a DocumentSnapshot with only 10 documents, Im passing a Variable with the desired amount of rows to limit and this variables catches the dropdown value to paginate, but anyways Im getting just 10 documents in the DocumentSnapshot as '10' is the first value Passed in the Variable to limit by.